# Adobe LiveCycle Designer Numeric Field set value

Tags: adobe, designer, livecycle

To Whom it may concern:

In a Adobe Form there is a Exchange Rate field, the rawValue is based on numeric field that has to be completed by the user.

The following code is what is used to do this under (formCalc, Client):

```
if     (Paid2.selectedIndex == "Cash")then
       Exch2.rawValue = AdvCash.rawValue
elseif (Exch2.selectedIndex == "Card") then
       Exch2.rawValue = ""
endif
```

The problem with above code is that once the user type in there own value for Card Exchange rate Exch2.rawValue and made a mistake and reselect "Cash" it does not run the first line of the If statement.

the last part of the question is how to add the following code into the above if then statement

**Exch2.rawValue.ui.oneOfChild.border.fill.color.value = " *, *, * "**

```
if     (Paid2.selectedIndex == "Cash")then
       Exch2.rawValue = AdvCash.rawValue
       Exch2.rawValue.ui.oneOfChild.border.fill.color.value = "229, 229, 229"
elseif (Exch2.selectedIndex == "Card") then
       Exch2.rawValue = ""
       Exch2.rawValue.ui.oneOfChild.border.fill.color.value = "255, 255, 153"
endif
```

The above **fill.color** does not provide the desired results.

Hope anybody can assist in this regard

Comment: try `Exch2.ui.oneOfChild.border.fill.color.value = "229, 229, 229"`

Answer (score 0):

- To your first issue:
  You are probably running the script in "wrong"(change?) event. Try to run in on exit event of the drop-down list.
- To your second issue:
  Remove rawValue in the Exch2.rawValue.ui.oneOfChild.border.fill.color.value = "255, 255, 153" and it should be good.